# Visual Studio 2013 feature to VS 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I forgot the name of the feature but I read once, that VS 2013 is able to automatically copy the CSS changes from the IE Developer Toolbar back to the css in your project...

1. How is that function called?
2. is there any (free or not free) tool to adopt this in VS 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature is [Browserlink with Web Essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/features/browserlink).  It is not available in VS 2012.

Comment: Maybe there is a tool for this?

Comment: I doubt it, since this is free (you can use the new Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition if you don't have a licence for VS2013).